# Flutter unable to obfuscate and strip symbols

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm unable to obfuscate or remove debug symbols as per this documentation
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/obfuscate

my command:

```
flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64 --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/symbols
```

output:

```
Could not find an option named "obfuscate".


Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to check that your are at least on the on 1.16.2 version of Flutter as explained [there](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/obfuscate) `Supported as of Flutter 1.16.2`

I'm currently on the 1.17.0 version and this command is working well :
`flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=<app_name>/symbols`

Comment: Document also says <app_name>. but project folder doesn't have app_name folder.

Comment: Ah, it is optional isn't it? it create new folder. not existing folder.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your flutter using

```
flutter upgrade
```

command and then use

```
flutter clean
```

command to clean any previous build cache then try again.

Answer (score -2):

One of the options which works is 
**--[no-]shrink**

```
flutter build apk --release --target-platform=android-arm64 --shrink
```

Whether to enable code shrinking on release mode. When enabling shrinking, you also benefit from obfuscation, which shortens the names of your app’s classes and members, and optimization, which applies more aggressive strategies to further reduce the size of your app.